# Tall cupcakes that have height to them

Tags: baking, cupcakes

I would like to bake mini cupcakes but need height on them before I use icing sugar. How do I get this right without the cupcake spilling over the paper and going flat and having no height to it?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about getting the absolute optimum amount of batter into each cupcake. Can you make one experimental batch before the "real" one? If so, very, very carefully measure infinitesimally larger amounts of batter in successive cupcakes. Take careful notes. One of the cupcakes will be perfect; use that measurement for all cupcakes in the next batch. If you've got a digital scale, this is a good reason to whip it out.

Comment: Even with perfect batter portioning discipline, inconsistent results are highly likely.  The oven temperature also would have to be ideal, for maximum spring while setting at the peak of volume.   Mini-cupcakes are very small, and magnify all of the unevenness present, including imperfect distribution of ingredients throughout the batch of batter (especially leavening), and hot and cold spots within the oven.